# Java update server not receiving client input

Tags: java, client-server, bufferedreader, dataoutputstream

I'm writing a server in Java that will give a response to the client, which sends the server the client name. Looking at the command line output from the server, it succesfully creates a connection to the client, but it's just stuck on waiting for the client name.

Here's the server code (pastebinned because it's a little bit long): http://pastebin.com/rwXT2AhU.

Here's the client code: (also pastebinned): http://pastebin.com/9xUpyhRA

Answer (score 0):

The server attempts to read the client name with the `readLine` method, which will wait until a newline character arrives. Try to send it after the client name.

Comment: Adding a newline after the client name worked perfectly! Thanks!